# Business Profile Performance: values are differente than GBP App

Tags: google-api, google-business-profile-api

I have a gap in values between the one returned by [Google Business Profile Performance API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations/getDailyMetricsTimeSeries) and the one in Google Business Profile application.

For example, on 14th July 2022, Google Business Profile Performance API give me a value to `28` for the `BUSINESS_DIRECTION_REQUESTS` metric.

The request parameters:

```json
{
  "dailyMetric": "BUSINESS_DIRECTION_REQUESTS",
  "dailyRange.startDate.day": 20,
  "dailyRange.startDate.month": 7,
  "dailyRange.startDate.year": 2021,
  "dailyRange.endDate.day": 17,
  "dailyRange.endDate.month": 7,
  "dailyRange.endDate.year": 2022,
  "name": "locations/10[...]19"
}
```

The response on 14th July:

```json
{
  "date": {
    "year": 2022,
    "month": 7,
    "day": 14
  },
  "value": "28"
}
```

For the same day, on Google Business Profile application, the graph of customer actions give me 40 itinirary requests:
[image]

How to explain this gap between values ?

Comment: I'm entirely unfamiliar with this service but, assuming that `BUSINESS_DIRECTION_REQUESTS` is equivalent to `Demande d'itineraire` and that the locations match, I wonder whether the disparity results from the different timezones. Which timezone is the API using? I assume the "14 juillet 2022" graph is localized to your timezone? Do you have a 3rd source that you could use to corroborate?

Comment: @DazWilkin I'm using UTC time to request Google's API: `new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 365)).setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);`
The location's timezone is UTC + 2, that gap is too short to explain that difference

Comment: If you assume that the metric is linear then, yes. I'd encourage you to remove differences between the two sets (i.e. query UTC+2 for both) in order to isolate the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where `BUSINESS_DIRECTION_REQUESTS` were much lower than their old, supposedly equivalent metric `actions_driving_directions`. I contacted Google Profile and this was their answer:

> “Going forward with the new Performance API multiple impressions by a unique user within a single day are counted as a single impression.”